# What is the difference between "liveReload" and "watchContentBase" in webpack devServer?

Tags: webpack, webpack-dev-server

Suppose `contentBase` is specified. These two options seem to me that they both enable the page to reload automatically when I make changes to the source files. What is the difference between these two options?